# Why the Django Template built-in tag filter {{ value | safe }} not working in the meta of head and script?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have rendered the value from backend to the html template.

In the body, `{{ value | safe }}` works well and removed the `<p>`, `<br>`, etc.

However, those html tags still show up when the `{{ value | safe }}` is in the meta of `<head>` and `<script>.`

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have figured it out!

```
{{ value|striptags|safe }}
```

works well in the meta of head and script

Comment: The Django [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags) say to never do `striptags|safe`, and suggest using `bleach.clean` as an alternative